# Dynamics CRM 2011/13 - Reenable onChange event on form field when user didn´t make changes

Tags: javascript, forms, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a validation method for an email form field, which is called on the onchange event of the field and sets the focus back on the field, if the validation fails:

```
function ValidateEMail(event) {

    var source = event.getEventSource();
    var value = source.getValue();
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/igm;

    if (value == '' || !re.test(value))
    {
      Xrm.Utility.alertDialog('Bitte geben Sie eine gültige E-Mail Adresse ein', null);
      Xrm.Page.getControl(event.getEventSource().getName()).setFocus(true);
      return false;    
    }
 }
```

}

The problem is that the onchange event is not fired again if the focus leaves the field the next time and the user didn´t make any changes. Unfortunately there is no lostFocus event I could use instead. Du you have any suggestions to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

1. Revalidate onsave and block save if the field is not valid
2. Clear the field (set to null) and make required.
3. Call change from within validate email but insert a condition to avoid infinit loop.
4. Use text field of type email and let crm do this stuff for you.
5. Use jquery and add binding to lost focus event

Answer (score 0):

This answer maybe a few months later but for future reference I would suggest the form field be customized as a Single Line of Text with a format option of "Email".

Setting the format option to "Email" will enable the client side validation of the user input on the field with no JavaScript required.

[Here is a reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531187.aspx#BKMK_SingleLineofTextFormatOptions) to the format options available for a Single Line of Text data type in Dynamics CRM.